# GUI Utillity that can simulate windows command tree /F /A

Tags: windows, file-management

I am looking for a GUI utility tool, or other purpose program that can display folder structure with files in tree view. I've seen that Total Commander can do it with folder structure but it's not very nice and clickable.

Is there anything else available?

Comment: Could you clarify "not very nice and clickable", I've always liked [FreeCommander](http://www.freecommander.com/), but it's essentially the same. What's your use case?

Answer (score 1):

The default GUI file manager in Linux Mint 18 (MATE edition) is "caja" and it does it in "list view" mode...

[image: caja file manager]

Comment: the question was tagged [tag:windows] so this doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

[Ffind](http://bvdsw.com/ffind/) can display folder structure with files, but in list view.